# EASA Part-NCO; Approach light system

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, easa-regulations, approach, instrument-procedures, easa

EASA Part-NCO, specifically OP.110, refers to 4 different lighting systems (NALS, BALS, IALS, FALS) to be considered when determining the landing minima. However, there are quite a few different systems, which in turn may vary in length, out there - nicely summarised in [this article](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53591/why-are-there-many-different-approach-lighting-systems)

Without using commercial vendors such as Jeppesen, how do you determine the lighting system "category" from the different plates?
Some examples, with the associated questions ahead of time:

- for EKSP below, a 900m Calvert, is that really a Calvert-2 and would be in the FALS category?
- And because 28L only has edge lighting, it would be NALS?
- For EDDH, is ALSAF always FALS? Especially since the "LEN" mentioned in the table's header isn't actually given in the table below it?

In short, how do I "map" the actual light system to the "category" of approach lighting systems?

Denmark, Skrydstrup EKSP:

[image: Approach and Runway Lighting EKSP]

Germany, Hamburg EDDH

[image: EDDH Ad 2.14]